# Does DOM adopt polymorphism?

Tags: oop, dom, polymorphism

Since the DOM is object-oriented, is it ok to say that it adopts the "four pillars of oop"?

It obviously adopts **inheritance**, for example with the parent-child relationships in the node tree.

Shadow DOM in Web Components can be given as an example for **encapsulation**.

Virtual DOM can be an adoption of **abstraction**.

However, I can't think of an example which could be used for saying that there's **polymorphism** in the DOM.

Would you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

DOM does not provide polymorphism because it is language independent but not a programming language in itself.

But these OOP concepts apply to languages that can manipulate the DOM, like JavaScript.